# TabBar is not showing another screen as a full screen - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: I need to create something like this]

I am using bottom navigation bar as my home page.
than in bottom navigation on item click opens a screen that contains `TabBarView` .
In my tab bar view on tap of container i am doing::

```
onTap: (){
                  // _tabController.animateTo(value)
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen(),fullscreenDialog: true));
                }
```

i get this output on the image shown below from the above code, i need to show second screen as a full screen like no app bar of tabbar screen.

Comment: Do you want to hide app bar and tabbar for a spesific screen?

Comment: yes sure@easeccy

Comment: do you know anything about this?? @Nardeepsinh Vaghela

Answer (score 3):

I found that to navigate from a screen with the appBar present, to one where the appBar is hidden, the best way that works for me is to modify the `MaterialPageRoute` slightly:

```
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        ),
      );
```

The key bit that does what you're looking for, for me, is adding `rootNavigator: true` to the command, since this pushes the page on top of the appBar.

Comment: Note that using the root navigator breaks screen tracking for analytics, because it can't provide a correct previous route on `RouteObserver.didPop`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide AppBar and TabBarView for spesific states, you can put conditions on your widget tree.

```
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  bool _control = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: _control
            ? AppBar(
                title: Text("Title Text"),
              )
            : null,
        body: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _control = !_control;
            });
          },
          child: Text('Toggle AppBar'),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: i have both different screen so set state will not worked

Comment: I need to know more about your apps structure. It depends on how you do state management.